# Content offset issue after watching video in iOS 8

Tags: rotation, ios8

I have a TabBarController, supportedInterfaceOrientations - UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait. Navigation bar moves up under the status bar when I start watching video from one of tabs, rotate device to landscape and then exit from fullscreen. Why it's happens and how fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of hack, but works in my view controller contains UIWebView and fullscreen videos start from <video> tags.

You will see jerking of navigation bar because `UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification` is called after video fullscreen window just disappear.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // NOTE: I'm not sure, but MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification won't work
    // [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowDidBecomeHidden:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowDidBecomeHidden:) name:UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)windowDidBecomeHidden:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIView *navbar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
    CGRect barFrame = navbar.frame;
    barFrame.origin.y = 20;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = barFrame;
    UIView *navbarBack = nil;
    for (UIView *view in navbar.subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqual:@"_UINavigationBarBackground"]) {
            navbarBack = view;
            break;
        }
    }
    CGRect backFrame = navbarBack.frame;
    backFrame.origin.y = -20;
    backFrame.size.height = 64;
    navbarBack.frame = backFrame;
    [navbar.superview setNeedsLayout];
}


UIView *navbarBack = [navbar.subviews bk_match:^BOOL(UIView *view) {
    return [NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqual:@"_UINavigationBarBackground"];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same issue.I tried to use js to get the "webkitendfullscreen" event,and then found navbar.frameOriginY = 0,which should be 20.